# Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but the Umbraco cannot connect to the database

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using **Umbraco CMS v7.4** with SQL Server 2014, the project was working fine until a few hours ago, when an error started showing up:

> Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but the Umbraco cannot connect to the database

The error occurs when I tried to open the website, see the image below:

[image]

I tried the following:

- Checked to see if **SQL Server** is running
- Checked the connection string **credentials** in `web.config`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few tries, even I loaded the backed up DB, I found that it caused by the DB login, the user in the connection string was having a password expiration enabled (the password had expired).

So, this is what I did:

- Open the SQL server
- Logged in as the user used in the connection string
- Created a new password
- Updated the web.config connection string "Password"

Hope this will help

Comment: Am still facing the same issue on azure, my connection strings seem correct, even when I run locally the website works , but it fails when I publish it on azure app services

Answer (score 1):

So, in my case I tried to get started with the existing project. I got all the files, restored DB backup locally, made sure all permissions are set for IIS AppPool user etc. But I kept getting the error in question. It turns out that I cannot use `server=localhost;database=...` in connection string. After I replaced it with `server=.\;database=...`, it started to work right away.

Comment: Is this with regard with azure ?

Answer (score 1):

Also note that if you're running it in Azure with an Azure SQL database you'll have to go to the Azure SQL Server settings and under "Firewalls and virtual networks" you'll need to tick "Yes" for "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server".

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when running an Umbraco project locally, with the DB pointing to an instance on Azure. In that case, this problem happens if you haven't allowed the IP access within the Server Firewall of the DB in Azure.

You can fix this by finding out your IP and then adding it to the DB:

- Click **All Resources** within your *Azure* portal, then click on the SQL Database your project points to.
- Click **Set Server Firewall** on the right-side window.
- Add in your *IP* as the start and end points, and call it something memorable.
- Click **Save** and once you get the confirmation message that *It has been applied*, refresh your site locally.

Comment: My firewall is set, but still having the issue, actually am using Azure  SQL and am hosting my Umbraco on azure. The other surprising thing the site was working , then later I found the error

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and here is how I fixed it.

- Right-click on your localhost in SSMS and select Properties
- Got to the Security page and select "Select authentication" as "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"
- Hit OK.
- Go to Services and find your SQL Server service and restart it.
- Check your local umbraco website now, you should be able to see it without any issues. If you still have problems, then you might need to check your local setup and permissions.
- Further details are below and [on this blog post](https://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2022/08/how-to-fix-umbraco-cannot-start.html).
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]